# preventDefault() cause problem on validating the form

Tags: javascript, html

the code below was written to validate simple html form with JavaScript and `preventDefault()` method means that if the required fields are empty then stop form submission and display error or otherwise submit the form if the required fields are not empty.

The problem comes when I click the submit button the form isn't working.
Can anyone please help me to solve the problem?

```js
let form = document.getElementById("signUp");
let uname = document.forms["myForm"]["userName"].value;
let uemail = document.forms["myForm"]["userEmail"].value;

function validateForm() {
  if (uname == " ") {
    alert("Name is Empty");
  } else if (uemail == " ") {
    alert("Email is Empty");
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
form.addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  validateForm();
});
```

```html
<form id="signUp" name="myForm">
  Name: <input type="text" name="uname" id="userName">
  <br> Email: <input type="email" name="email" id="userEmail">
  <button type="submit">sign up</button>
</form>
```

Comment: `if(validateForm()) { form.submit(); }` <-- you must submit manually and the return false must be in all two if

Comment: e.preventDefault() is used to catch the default behavior of submit so at the moment you use e.preventDefault() the form can no longer be trigger automatically and you have to submit it using javascript login. In the other hand if you only want to validate if the fields are empty, there are the html attribute `required` or other simple built in attributes https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation

Comment: @Vincent Rouilhac
 can u help to improve the code? demonstrate the working solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `e.preventDefault()` you say that the form should not be submitted.
So you only want to call if in case the validation returns false.

Besides that, your `uname` and `uemail` is set before the form is submitted. So it won't contain the state of the input fields at the time the form is submitted. You have to move them into your `validateForm` function.

```js
let form = document.getElementById("signUp");

function validateForm() {
  let uname = document.forms["myForm"]["userName"].value;
  let uemail = document.forms["myForm"]["userEmail"].value;
  if (uname == " ") {
    alert("Name is Empty");
  } else if (uemail == " ") {
    alert("Email is Empty");
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
form.addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
  if (!validateForm()) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```html
<form id="signUp" name="myForm">
  Name: <input type="text" name="uname" id="userName">
  <br> Email: <input type="email" name="email" id="userEmail">
  <button type="submit">sign up</button>
</form>
```

And `uname == " "` does not test if the name is empty. It tests if it consists of one character that is a space. The same is for `uemail == " "`. You probably looking for `uname.trim() == ""`

As you need to verify the data on the server anyways. And in some way need to display an error if the validation fails on the server side.

It is often sufficient to rely on the HTML solutions to verify the form data (if the browser support is decent enough even if it is not complete).

Something like this:

```css
.error {
  display: none;
}

input:not(:placeholder-shown):invalid +.error {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<form id="signUp" name="myForm">
  Name: <input type="text" name="uname" id="userName" placeholder="Name" pattern="^(?!^ +$)([\w -&]+)$" required>
  <div class="error">Name must not be empty</div>
  <br> Email: <input type="email" name="email" id="userEmail" placeholder="Email" required>
  <div class="error">Email must be valid</div>
  <button type="submit">sign up</button>
</form>
```

Comment: did u run the code?? i see the form is submitting even when the required fields are empty

Comment: @willy did you read the text below the code? You don't test for the fields being empty but for the fields containing a space.

Comment: works fine now i got confused by writing " " instead of ""

Answer (score 2):

```js
const form = document.getElementById("signUp");
form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  if(validate()) {
    form.submit()  
  }
});

const validate = () => {
   const name = document.querySelector("#userName");
   const email = document.querySelector("#email");
   let hasError = false;
   
   if(!(name.value && name.value.length > 4)) {
      const nameErr = document.querySelector("#user-name-error");
      nameErr.textContent = "Name is required";
      hasError = true;
   }
   
   if(!(name.value && name.value.length > 0)) {
      const emailErr = document.querySelector("#user-email-error");
      emailErr.textContent = "Email is required";
      hasError = true;
   }
   
   return !hasError;
};
```

```html
<form id="signUp" name="myForm">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="userName">Name: </label>
    <input type="text" name="uname" id="userName" />
    <p id="user-name-error" style="color: red;"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="userEmail">Email: </label>
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" />
    <p id="user-email-error" style="color: red;"></p>
  </div>
  <button type="submit">sign up</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

```html
<form id="signUp" name="myForm">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="userName">Name: </label>
    <input type="text" name="uname" id="userName" required minlength="4"/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="userEmail">Email: </label>
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" required pattern="[^@]*@[^.]*\..*"/>
  </div>
  <button type="submit">sign up</button>
</form>
```

This is an example using only html, it is only for your use case of course if you want to add more complexe validation use javascript

Comment: I agree that JavaScript is not required here. And I didn't downvote. But the question is about a problem with the JavaScript code, so the answer should target that problem. In addition to that, a solution without JavaScript can for sure still be added.

Comment: @t.niese  how can we achieve the same thing by putting  the preventDefault(); outside of this function?    if (!validateForm()) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }